# How to specify equivalent of Dockerfile RUN for bazel container_image rule?

Tags: dockerfile, bazel

I'm converting a Dockerfile to a bazel `container_image` rule. How would I specify a `RUN` specification for `container_image`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[container_run_and_commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docker/util/README.md#container_run_and_commit) will run commands and make a new layer with the result, which is similar to `RUN`. Something like this:

```py
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/util:run.bzl", "container_run_and_commit")

container_run_and_commit(
  name = "x",
  commands = ["touch /xyz"],
  image = ":my_base.tar",
)
```

The `image` argument is a `docker save`-style tarball. You can bring this in via an external repository, or use the implicit `.tar` output from a `container_image` rule. My example above will work if you have a `container_image(name = "my_base")` in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your use-case, but in case it is for anyone else,

If you are just trying to get a `docker run` type of execution on a container image using `bazel run :my_container`.

you can do this by setting `legacy_run_behavior` to false. This attribute isn't clearly documented because I think it's part of a seperate package manager rule.

```
container_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "my_base_image",
    legacy_run_behavior = False,
    tars = [
        "my_files",
    ],
)
```